# How to get Angular controller members in non-Angular code?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-controller

I'm sticking my toe in the Angular ocean.  I have a web application that uses jQuery to allow the user to interact with the application using input forms and buttons.  I'm learning Angular and as an exercise, I decided to try to write code to do this with Angular instead.

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MainFormCtrl as Form">
```

I used the `ng-app` and `ng-controller` directives as above to make my application use an Angular controller I've written.

I use the `ng-model` directive with each input the user can enter data into.  I use the form `ng-model="Form.inputs.xxxxx"` because I want to be able to pass around the collection of input values as a single object.

I have written code in my controller that provides default values for these inputs.  I am still using my existing code to read the values from the DOM.  I understand that once I've declared my model and controller, Angular magically allows me to pass around the model so that I can read it and make changes to it elsewhere in my program.

I've attached a method called `getInputs` to my Angular controller.  How can I call this member function (or get other members of the controller object) from non-Angular code?  If that isn't practical, what sort of solution should I use.

Comment: what does the non-angular code do, exactly?  Angular is just a framework, it isn't changing the way that JavaScript operates;  That being said, there are things you can do to ensure that Angular is able to keep up with what you are doing.

Comment: the short answer is probably this: if your ng-model is `Form.inputs.xxxxx`, Angular will automatically create a variable in it's `$scope` object to track changes to that model.  Your controller would have access to `$scope.Form.inputs.xxxxx` as a value, two way bound.

Comment: I have a few minutes, we can use a chat and try to discuss your specific case, if you would like? let me know.

Comment: actually, in your code, since you are using the ControllerAs syntax, `inputs` would just be a property of your controller, so `inputs.xxxxx` would work, without using `$scope`.

Comment: I'm not sure if my question was clear to you, @Claies.  I am trying to access the contents of the controller from non-Angular code.  I'm not sure if that's allowed.  I am in the AngularJS chatroom now.

Comment: You say that I can access `$scope.Form.inputs.xxxxx`, but how do I access that from outside the controller?

Comment: sorry I had to step out for a bit.  I understand what you are asking; but in terms of Angular, it doesn't really make sense to access the controller in non-angular ways.  I was more curious what your non-angular code does, and if it could be called from the controller, passing the form values in as parameters.... or if it could be wrapped in an Angular service method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access controller from non-angular code by

```
$("[ng-controller='MainFormCtrl']").scope()
```

Edited to show how to access scope & all method within controller using Jquery(above) & non-Jquery(below)

```
document.getElementById('yourControllerElementID').scope()
```

Comment: This isn't working.  I just get an array with one element in it, and I don't see any way to access the controller from it.

Comment: Also, I'm trying to use Angular instead of jQuery, but this answer uses jQuery.  Doing a quick search, it seems like there should be some way to do this without using jQuery.